# Ending support for multiplayer APIs in Play Games Services

Tags: actionscript-3, air

By this announcement

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9469745

Starting on 31 March 2020, we’ll be ending support for real-time and turn-based multiplayer APIs. If your game includes real-time and turn-based multiplayer integration, you will be unable to turn these features off and can continue using them until 31 March 2020. These APIs cannot be enabled for new games.

What are your alternative solutions for adobe air multiplayer games?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be [gamesparks.com](https://docs.gamesparks.com/sdk-center/actionscript.html) which still supports AIR.

[Player.io](https://playerio.com/) also supports multiplayer in AIR and as3.

A more classic approach is the old [Smart Fox Server](https://www.smartfoxserver.com/) for as3.

I hope these help.